# Calculating total sum of line segments overlapping on a line

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the total sum of overlapping line segments across a single line. With line A, the segments are disjointed, so it's pretty simple to calculate. However, with lines B and C, there are overlapping line segments, so it's more complicated. I would need to somehow exclude parts of the previous lines that already part of the total sum.

```
data = read.table(text="
    line    left_line   right_line  small_line  left_small_line right_small_line
    A   100 120 101 91  111
    A   100 120 129 119 139
    B   70  90  63  53  73
    B   70  90  70  60  80
    B   70  90  75  65  85
    C   20  40  11  1   21
    C   20  40  34  24  44
    C   20  40  45  35  55", header=TRUE)
```

This should be the expected result.

```
result = read.table(text="
    total_overlapping
A   0.6
B   0.75
C   0.85", header=TRUE)
```

EDIT: Added a picture to better illustrate what I'm trying to figure out. There's 3 different pictures of lines (solid red line), with line segments (the dashed lines) overlapping. The goal is to figure out how much of the dashed lines are covering/overlapping.

Line A
[image: Line A:]

Line B 
[image: Line B:]
Line C  [image: Lince C:]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code attempt.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I could do that. I will post a picture soon of what the goal I want.

Comment: I don't understand what the figure has to do with your data. Where in the figure are `left_line`, `right_line`, `small_line`, `left_small_line`, `right_small_line`? I don't see the connection to the different dashed/solid lines.

Comment: The left_line represents the left side/border of the line, same for the right. The small_line represents the center of the line segment (dashed line), and the right and left are the borders/sides of the line segments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `small_line` variable is irrelevant here. The rest of the columns can be used to get the sum of overlapping segments:

**Step 1**. Get the start & end point for each segment's overlap with the corresponding line:

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(overlap.start = max(left_line, left_small_line),
         overlap.end = min(right_line, right_small_line)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(line, overlap.start, overlap.end)

> data1
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  line  overlap.start overlap.end
  <fct>         <int>       <int>
1 A               100         111
2 A               119         120
3 B                70          73
4 B                70          80
5 B                70          85
6 C                20          21
7 C                24          40
8 C                35          40
```

**Step 2**. Within the rows corresponding to each line, sort the overlaps in order. consider it a new overlapping section if it is the first overlap, OR the previous overlap ends before it started. Label each new overlapping section:

```
data2 <- data1 %>%
  arrange(line, overlap.start, overlap.end) %>%
  group_by(line) %>%
  mutate(new.section = is.na(lag(overlap.end)) | 
           lag(overlap.end) <= overlap.start) %>%
  mutate(section.number = cumsum(new.section)) %>%
  ungroup()

> data2
# A tibble: 8 x 5
  line  overlap.start overlap.end new.section section.number
  <fct>         <int>       <int> <lgl>                <int>
1 A               100         111 TRUE                     1
2 A               119         120 TRUE                     2
3 B                70          73 TRUE                     1
4 B                70          80 FALSE                    1
5 B                70          85 FALSE                    1
6 C                20          21 TRUE                     1
7 C                24          40 TRUE                     2
8 C                35          40 FALSE                    2
```

**Step 3**. Within each overlapping section, take the earliest starting point & the latest ending point. Calculate the length of each overlap:

```
data3 <- data2 %>%
  group_by(line, section.number) %>%
  summarise(overlap.start = min(overlap.start),
            overlap.end = max(overlap.end)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(overlap = overlap.end - overlap.start)

> data3
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  line  section.number overlap.start overlap.end overlap
  <fct>          <int>         <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>
1 A                  1           100         111      11
2 A                  2           119         120       1
3 B                  1            70          85      15
4 C                  1            20          21       1
5 C                  2            24          40      16
```

**Step 4**. Sum the length of overlaps for each line:

```
data4 <- data3 %>%
  group_by(line) %>%
  summarise(overlap = sum(overlap)) %>%
  ungroup()

> data4
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  line  overlap
  <fct>   <dbl>
1 A          12
2 B          15
3 C          17
```

Now, your expected result shows the expected *percentage* of overlap on each line, rather than the sum. If that's what you are looking for, you can add the length for each line to `data4`, & calculate accordingly:

```
data5 <- data4 %>%
  left_join(data %>% 
              select(line, left_line, right_line) %>%
              unique() %>% 
              mutate(length = right_line - left_line) %>%
              select(line, length),
            by = "line") %>%
  mutate(overlap.percentage = overlap / length)

> data5
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  line  overlap length overlap.percentage
  <fct>   <dbl>  <int>              <dbl>
1 A          12     20               0.6 
2 B          15     20               0.75
3 C          17     20               0.85
```